# Unable to assign [undefined] to QString

Tags: qml

I am new to QML so kindly help me out as why QML throws error when trying to build this one

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
        
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("App title")
        
    ListModel {
        id: modelName
        
        ListElement { name: "alpha" }
        ListElement { name: "beeta" }
        ListElement { name: "gamma" }
    }
        
    Component {
        id: delegateName
        
        Text {
            text: modelName.name   // QML throw error here
            font.pixelSize: 32     
        }
    }
        
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: modelName
        delegate: delegateName
        clip: true
    }
}
```

I'm building this using QT-Creator. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a delegate, try this one: `text: model.name`. Every delegate has its own model property with accordingly model's data

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem but can you explain why modelName.name doesn't work ?

Comment: @dummyaccount modelName is a list model. You want to get value from a name property.  As you can see, it hasn't this property (only contains ListElement). In QML, access to not defined property causes error ( e.g. `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString`).

Comment: You can see more [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html)